# How to create a controller action called 'event'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to add an action to my controller called 'event', but that's a reserved word. What's the easiest way to add an event action?

Eg:

```
public class entertainmentController : Controller
{
    // GET: entertainment
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: entertainment/event
    public ActionResult event()  // <-- won't compile
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it hurt to give it a capital E?

Comment: Yes, we want to preserve existing urls.

Comment: The URL would be case insensitive I think...

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize that. Though I think generated urls would have uppercase E and you might end up with a mix of conventions in the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ActionName attribute

```
// GET: entertainment/event
[ActionName("event")]
public ActionResult EntertainmentEvent()
{
    return View("EntertainmentEvent");
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Just had to add return View("EntertainmentEvent"); because you can't create a view called "event" either.

Comment: @pixelmike - Ah yes, the views need to be named accordingly, nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

While I'd recommend against it, this will compile:

```
public ActionResult @event()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Ohh that looks evil. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in route mapping. just add a route `entertainment/event` in RouteConfig and map that route to a custom action..lets say 'randomAction'